# Cyclic docker container restart (linux server)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

So i want to cyclically restart my docker container (once a week - let's say Sunday, 22:00)
Does anyone know how to call *docker restart ID* every Sunday?

Comment: Why are you restarting your container? Do you mean re-deploy? Upgrade? Trivially stopping and starting a container seems a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: If you do a sleep for a 1 week end then run killl 1 inside the container, it will go down after a wekk. If you combine this with restart policy it will come right back up.

Comment: @bobdylan it diesnt seem like a bad idea. You never know what the developers give you to deploy there.  If there is memory leaks or other bugs, all we can do from the operating side is restarting the process. Of course if dev would fix this, it would be better but its likely not going to happen. If you don't want to get called at 3am because of them, then better restart the container sometimes.

Comment: @TheFool - it'll come back up without the sleep (possibly) and it'd need to be x mins after deployment time (e.g. deployed on sunday). I think the easiest way would be to just use cron as it's a simple way to `just do it` - however I still don't know his use-case

Comment: sleep 1 week then kill 1 is for dying after that period.  Then the restart=always or restart=on-failure will just bring it back up. Cron may be cleaner but this dirty hack can be implented by adjusting the normal run command a bit.

Comment: Yes but sleep 1 week will still be dependent upon when the first run is invoked - is my point to your answer. However given the fact you think just restarting a container to hide developer issues is a suitable fix shows the difference in mentality and approach. IF they were asking how to deploy :latest on schedule then I'd agree (despite how trivial the change is) this is a workaround that has real applications. To issue a docker restart containerid command just sounds lazy and ill-thought.

Comment: Further to this - you say you don't want a developer calling you at 3am? Could it be because the developer has been allowed to call people at 3am in the first place that it's then become 'their' problem - when it always was? If the developer had to wait until 9am they'd soon be more self-reflective upon the mess they've created. If a developer is calling anyone for a non-prod issue at 3am then I'd consider changing company pronto.

Comment: The thing is that i have a web app set up in docker on linux server in my company, during the weekend IT department often do some magic work in networking - and this is screwing up my ethernet interface in my app, that's why i want to restart it every sunday - restart will load the new eth interface settings

Comment: When did I once say they can't do it? I said if they're going to be quick and dirty about it - use cron to issue the command(s) and forget about it. I'm saying - you can be quick and dirty about it, but put 2 seconds more effort in and gain the value of doing an auto-deployment or blue / green, rolling patching etc. AT THE SAME TIME.

Comment: @Sir_Hubsi you could use a health check and check there to see if network interface is still good. If not you do again a kill 1. Then restart policy will bring it back up. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Comment: @TheFool Thanks for that hint  i would add the HEALTCHECK  for sure. What if the IT department power reset the serwer -  how to add the docker run to startup process in linux?

Comment: you just do a `systemctl enable docker`, and then with `--restart always`, it will start docker on server bootup and that container.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about - eeking out the real issue and discarding all the presumptions meant we're able to come across a better / the correct solution. As with most things there's alternatives ways to 'end up with the same', but that doesn't mean it should be done. I agree sometimes you just need to get it done - but clearly in this example it wasn't a JFDI situation and he had the time to do it right. Everyone should still be conscious to promote better standards and practices, for themselves, and I recognized this gap - but what do I know I've 'never worked with prod code' - right?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a restart policy with the `docker run` command, and use the `-d` parameter which Docker recommends,

More information in the docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Update:

1. Create a cron job to restart the docker container on Sunday at 22:00.
2. The Docker restart policy should start the container again.
3. Create an anacron job inside the container, to launch your program after the Docker container starts again.